# What does ダークホース mean here?

Tags: translation

I am vainly trying to understand the paragraph below but I am running into some difficulties. In particular, I have a lot of difficulties to figure out exactly what is meant by ダークホース here (there is a comics publisher whose name is Dark Horse but I think it is irrelevant here). The other point is `予測した私は` where I am not sure about `who estimates what`.

The extract:

> この小説について
>   とあるご縁でお会いしたガガガ編集部の面々は、たいへん濃い方々でした。
>   彼らが求める小説は、きっととんがった内容ばかりになるじゃろう。
>   **と広島弁で予測した私は、あえてひとりだけの作風でダークホースしようとして…**
>   軽く失敗して横道スピンしてできたのがこの小説です。

My attempt at translating it:

> About this novel.
>   A certain acquaintance introduced me to the publishing house GAGAGA, they were so much enthusiastic people. They wanted a story polished to perfection. **With a distinct accent from Hiroshima, I explained that I tried at best to write in a unique and pleasant style and sought I might success even if at the beginning anybody has any hopes about my work.** I slightly failed and sometimes wandered away from the path but here is the novel I wrote.

Here I translated ダークホース by a periphrase explaining that a “dark horse” may well be a horse that has been overlooked in a horse race but will win anyway. The image hinted by the dark horse may be reused by 横道スピン but I did not include it in the translation.

Comment: @chocolate 改訂しました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ダークホース](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/132239/meaning/m0u/) itself is a well-known horse racing term, but ダークホースする is not common. Anyway, I guess this ダークホースする means exactly what you suggest ("to succeed although there was no expectation from others").

I think you have gotten some phrases wrong:

- 濃い here is a slang term meaning "unique", "eccentric", "having strong character", etc.
- とんがった is another casual expression which refers to the opposite of what you think. It's "very unique (although it may be rough around the edges)", "individualistic", "avant-garde", etc.
- 予測 is "to anticipate", you have to stick to the literal translation.
- 軽く here is "so easily" with maybe a bit sarcastic nuance. It implies "as a natural consequence", "as everyone could easily expect", etc.
- 横道スピン is a car racing term, so I don't think it's a reference to ダークホース.

So the author tried to write a novel with a very unique style, thinking that's what the editors were expecting. But he admits he simply failed, and the result was not a unique masterpiece but something only strange.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. It really helps me.